# How mining works?

Tags: mining-theory

In order to mine bitcoin, a node needs to have all 60+ GB of blockchain data and read them for every transaction? Or exists a more efficient way to mine blocks?

Comment: Could you please edit the title to better represent your question?

Answer (score 1):

> In order to mine bitcoin, a node needs to have all 60+ GB of blockchain data

No. But if it wants to include transactions in its blocks, it has to know which transactions are valid and which aren't.

> and read them for every transaction? Or exists a more efficient way to mine blocks?

Typically, you process all that data once, maintaining an efficient, indexed database of unspent transaction outputs (UTXOs). You can tell if a transaction is valid by (in addition to the other needed checks) just checking its inputs against your UTXO database. You don't need to go fishing through 60GB of raw, unindexed data.